# GCP: Is it possible to have an access to a resource if don't have project access?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It is my first expirience in Google Cloud Platform and I'm confused.
I've got an access to a resource:

> xxx@gmail.com has granted you the following roles for resource **resource_name**(projects/project_name/datasets/ClientsExport/tables/resource_name) **BigQuery Data Editor**

But if I open BigQuery Data Editor, I don't see project_name and resource_name. Search by resource_name also returns no result.

Is it only access that I have in the project (I didn't get another accesses and mails).

Could you please help me with this? Maybe should I get some additional access to resource_name will be available? If is there another way to find the resource?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In the message you have access to BigQuery data inside a table. You can query them from your project, you are autorised to access them (and to write also, because you are editor).

However, this table isn't in your project, it's in another project that's why you don't see it directly in the BigQuery console. In addition, you haven't the right to read the metadata (roles/bigquery.metadataViewer) on the dataset of the other project. Eventually, you can't also view the table schema in the console, but the bq CLI allow you to view it.

I had some discussions with Google BigQuery team about that (because I got the same issue in my company), and updates should happen by the end of the year (or soon in 2022) to fix this "view" issue in the console.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have IAM permission to access a specific resource in BigQuery but cannot access it from the GUI.

Some reasons you may not see access on your GUI:

- You have permission to interact with BigQuery but don't have access to any of the data.
- You aren't a member of the organization which provided the resources and they have higher level permissions (on the org level) which prevents sharing of resources outside of the org.
- Your access is restricted to the command line/app level. (If your account is a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) then this is likely the case.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll ask person that granted access about 1st and 2nd points. As 3rd point - could you kindly clarify how to check and fix it if possible?

Comment: Give the following docs a read: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts @YuA -> highlight _"A service account is a special kind of account used by an application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person."_

Comment: Service accounts cannot access the Google Cloud Console GUI. In this case, the **BigQuery Data Editor** role is granted to a Gmail user for only one BigQuery table. If the user has no other roles, access via the Console will be restricted.